# OpsHub Team Project not found

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

Earlier this week, we performed a migrated a Team Project from TFS 2010 to Visual Studio Online using the OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility.  We performed the migration as a test.  During this test migration we did not properly all of the users since we had yet to add everyone's Microsoft accounts to Visual Studio Online.

Our intentions were to run the migration as a test, verify that the changesets and work items were migrated properly, then delete and re-create the Team Project on Visual Studio Online.  At that point, we would migrate the Team Project again, over the weekend, and start active development against the new Visual Studio Online Team Project on Monday.

When I try to run the migration again, however, an exception is thrown when it's trying to create the configuration:

[image: OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility]

I can assure you that the Team Project exists on Visual Studio Online.  I can see it on the portal, and I can see it if I connect using Visual Studio.

What am I missing?  Why did the migration work initially, but fail when I try to migrate again, after deleting the initial Team Project and re-creating it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how my Visual Studio Online Team Project got into the state that it was in, however I was able to finally re-migrate. Once again, I deleted my Team Project, this time also deleting all of the associated Team Rooms (I'm not sure that this made any difference, but since they were named after the Team Project, I went ahead and deleted them). I then recreated the Team Project.

At this time, the OpsHub configuration was successful and the migration was able to start and proceed as expected.

Comment: Hi, It is quite likely the issue might be due to insufficient permission to the end point user for that project. Nevertheless, glad you could get it working. - OpsHub